# Not changing boolean

Tags: java, for-loop, math

I have a method for testing if a number is a prime number. I have tested the method with 8445, which is not prime because it can be divided by 3. Although the for loop has the 3 as you can see in console, it prints true. That println is in the main method of which I did not take a picture.

```
public boolean Primzahlerkennen(int i) 
{
    boolean bool = true;

    for (int a = 2; a < i; a ++) {
        if (i % a == 0)
            bool = false;
        else
            a++;

        if (a==3){
            System.out.println("here "+a);
            System.out.println(8445%3);
        }
    }

    return bool;
}
```

Why doesn't the value change to false although `8445 % 3 == 0`?

Comment: Please provide method source

Comment: Don't use images to show your code! Paste it here.

Comment: Your problem in your inefficient prime testing function is the `else a++;` part. You increment `a` in the loop already - doing it again will cause numbers to be skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you increment `a` twice, once in the `for` statement and once in the body of the loop itself.

This causes your loop to skip some divisors (three being one of them).

Further suggestions:

1. Give your boolean variable a name that reflects its purpose (and not `bool`).
2. You don't need to check even divisors other than 2 since none of them are prime.
3. You can stop the loop at `sqrt(i)` (figuring out why this is correct is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Thank you solved it now with a while loop to avoid two variables and it worked.